# Не выполняется большой запрос в скрипте

Tags: mysql, sql

Запрос большой на Select, в workbench'е за 1500 сек отпрабатывает, через скрипт, используя mysqli, несколько секунд работает и результата нет, ошибок тоже никих не выдает.

Задал вначале скрипта

```
set_time_limit(6000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Делаю так:

```
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) error_log("error ungraded_allcourses_rd",0);
var_dump($result);
```

Вот что выдает результат через 65 сек в консоли

```
object(mysqli_result)#29 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(6)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

UPD: На следующий день до кэширования видимо запроса, в консоли тоже выполняется 1500 сек, тоесть все видимо выполняется нормально, но почему то не возвращает результат

UPD+: В общем заметил что без этой строчки в запросе все работает хорошо

```
WHERE l.eventname = '\\mod_assign\\event\\assessable_submitted'
```

Явно он не находит соответствие по условию, и похоже дело в экранировании слэша, но в workbench все работает хорошо

Comment: А что сделать, то нужно?

Comment: @lazyproger обычный запрос на select

Comment: Вы пишете, что у вас запрос работает в Workbench 1500 сек, т.е. 25 минут, чего вы ожидаете через несколько секунд работы через приложение?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko что бы скрипт в консоли не завершался через несколько секунд?

Comment: *несколько секунд работает и результата нет, ошибок тоже никих не выдает.* Так не бывает. Результат есть ВСЕГДА. Может, Вы его забываете получить (например, подавив ошибки) или неправильно это делаете?

Comment: Почему запрос так долго обрабатывается? Сколько таблиц затронуто? Сколько строк в таблицах? Используются-ли индексы? Что по этому поводу написано в логах? Это пока не все вопросы, ответами на которые нужно дополнить ваш вопрос

Comment: @Akina Дополнил вопрос

Comment: предлагаю проверить идентичность настроек подключения в части таймаутов. А какие параметры передаются в запрос? Есть подозрение, что по передаваемым параметрам результирующая выборка пустая

Comment: @SergeNazarenko параметров никаких, да и в workbench запрос нормально отрабатывает

Comment: @SergeNazarenko Может теперь есть идеи?)

Comment: @РусланРуслан копнуть в сторону экранирования, есть там какая-то проблема в mysqli с этим. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php